# How Can I do punching of 0.22mm in stainless steel sheet (Sheet thickness 0.5mm)

Tags: hydraulics, metals, power-engineering, cnc, drilling

Wanted to press punching of 0.22mm dia (Bottom) and on (top) 0.6mm dia

Please suggest how can I make such die?

[image]

Comment: What concerns do you have? Why do you think that this will be an issue?

Comment: I suggest you don't make a die to punch a 0.009 " ( I only think in English) hole in tough stainless steel ( assuming 304 or 316 ). Are you trying to make a die for extrusion ?

Comment: @blacksmith37 when the question was asked in metric, why answer in imperial? Then double down when an explicit statement about it?

Comment: I practice both units, but always find it is difficult to visualize metric size in my head, I believe the reverse is true for many people.

Comment: The point is , you can't make a punch that diameter regardless of  whether you call it mm or in.

Comment: Espresso filter?

Answer (score 0):

You could "micro metal etch" the pattern either onto a stamp or onto a die.  This kind of thing is done by these companies:

http://www.microetchtech.com/guidelines-chemically-etching-part-dimensions

https://www.micrometal.de/en.html

Answer (score 0):

Why use stamping to make molds?
If a lower cost approach is used, such as a chemical etching process.
In any case, the cost of wet chemical etching will be much, much cheaper than the mold you make.

You can find the following companies that can do wet chemical etching of stainless steel for you:
https://wetetched.com/etching-precision-machined-stainless-steel/
https://www.chemcut.net/products/etching/
https://www.masteretching.com/chemical-etching-process
https://www.precisionmicro.com/chemical-etching-a-step-by-step-guide/
https://metaletching.com/what-is-chemical-etching/
https://www.hysonetch.com/photo-etching-applications/